# Azure pipeline selenium save screenshot

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an azure pipeline that triggers a python selenium scrip that check that my website works properly.

But there is a stage that keeps failing because I need selenium to input a specific date, and as I am not sure if the date inputed is in the wrong format (locally works just fine) I would like to take a screenshot at that stage to fully understand what is happening in there.

locally this is my configuration to save the screenshot:

```
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/main/div[4]/div/button[2]'))).click()
except:
    driver.save_screenshot('error.png')
```

This works just fine and it does output the png image in the local folder.
but running this on azure pipeline, is not saving the png file.

this is my pipeline configuration

```
stages:
  - stage:
    jobs:
      - job: Configuration
        steps:
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '3.8'
              addToPath: true
          - script: |
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              pip install selenium
              printenv
          - task: Pythonscript@0
            inputs:
              scriptSource: 'filePath'
              scriptPath: './script1.py'
            env:
              USERNAMEOT: $(usernameot)
              PASSWORDOT: $(passwordot)
      - job: Artifact
        steps:
          - task: CopyFiles@2
            displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
            inputs:
              SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
              Contents: '**.png'
              TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
              flattenFolders: true
          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: 'Publish Artifact: screenshots'
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
              ArtifactName: screenshots
```

I do have a task to copy file and publish the artefact, but as this task runs in parallel, it completes before the previous job and return nothing.
I was wandering how can I save the png file I have to the artefact folder even if the `Configuration` job fails?

Thank you so much for any help you can provide me guys, I am really struggling on this

Answer (score 0):

> I was wandering how can I save the png file I have to the artefact folder even if the Configuration job fails?

You could try to set the Dependencies and condition for the job `Artifact`, like:

```
jobs:
- job: Artifact
  dependsOn: Configuration
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

With the `dependsOn: Configuration`, the job `Artifact` will executed after the job `Configuration`. And the `condition: succeededOrFailed()` will keep the job `Artifact` execute when the Configuration job fails.

You could check the document [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#dependencies) for some more details.